# Get Stripe Connected AccountsID Using Client Address Email

Tags: stripe-payments

Using Stripe API, I built a Marketplace App. When the clients add their account to my stripe connect, I'm trying to get the client AccountID so I can do payout processing.

For the moment, I'm using Stripe's object (List all connected accounts). It returns a JSON object but I don't know how to get the client AccountID using client email address.

If anyone can help me to do this using cURL or PHP or java ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to [fetch](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve) or [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/list) Stripe Accounts by email address using the Stripe API.

The best approach would be to store an account ID to email address mapping on your end so you can find the account ID without listing all accounts using the Stripe API.